# How to change selected text without mouse button release

Tags: c++, linux, qt, selection, clipboard

I am writing small c++ application using QT creator and i have a problem, I want to get selecting text from any application, I am using to this QClipboard library (`SIGNAL(selectionChanged())`), but it doesn't work properly admittedly i am getting selected text, but only after I release a mouse button. I would like to get selected text in "real time" without mouse button up. Is there any simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to add this header file: QClipboard

then...

```
connect(qApp->clipboard, SIGNAL(selectionChanged), this, SLOT(your_slot()));

void your_slot() {
    QClipboard *clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
    clipboard->setText(qApp->clipboard->text());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html#selectionChanged

It looks like that is only supported well on X11, like Linux.

If you are interested in tracking mouse selections in your program in realtime, you can look directly at the mouse events or keyboard events, or the Rich Text Processing framework (`QTextCursor`).

You could also send a `copy` call while the mouse is down on a timer, and then look at the `dataChanged` signal.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer. You are right, it works on Linux only and I work on Debian. 
The problem is that I want get selected text from any application not only from my program. A copy signal would be a good solution, but I need function which works "global". Is there function which copies selected text to clipboard from any application?